# Converting units of m day-1 (ERA5) to mm (CRU)

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, climate

I have downloaded 2 datasets, one from CRU (https://data.ceda.ac.uk/badc/cru/data/cru_ts/cru_ts_3.00/data) of cru_ts_3_00.1901.2006.pre.nc.gz and other is ERA5 data (https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/ecv-for-climate-change?tab=form) of Precipitation. The CRU data units for precipitation is mm as stated in https://dap.ceda.ac.uk/badc/cru/doc/File_Format_CRUTS3.00.pdf and ERA5 data is in m day-1 as stated in https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/ecv-for-climate-change?tab=overview. Now I have opened and converted both of the datasets into raster format in R. However I want to make the units same. How can I convert m day-1(ERA5 data) to mm(CRU data)?

Answer (score 3):

CRU is mm/month, ERA is m/day. So it depends on the number of days in the month. But for January you could divide CRU by 31000 or multiply ERA with 31000

Say you had an mean rainfall of 10 mm/day, ERA would report 0.01 and CRU would report 310 (for a month with 31 days).

```
310 / 31000
#[1] 0.01
0.01 * 31000
#[1] 310
```

As a function perhaps like this

```
era_to_cru <- function(era, days_in_month) {
   era * 1000 * days_in_month
}
era_to_cru(0.01, 31)
#[1] 310
```